# Show that if $p$ is a prime number, and $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_p$, then $G$ must contain a cycle of length $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Note that a subgroup $G$ of $S_n$ is called a *transitive subgroup* of $S_n$ if it acts transitively on the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$.

I understand that for any $x$, $y$ $\in \{1,2,...,p\}$, there exists an element $g \in G$ such that $g x=y$, but I do not know how to use this to demonstrate the existence of a $p$-cycle.

This comes in a section of text about group actions, which is before discussion of Sylow Theorems, so I presume the proof will not require them. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Show that $p | |G|$ and use Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the orbit stabilizer theorem and transitivity, the number of cosets of the stabilizer of a point is $p$. In particular, as in a hint you received in a comment, the order of the group is divisible by $p$. By Cauchy's theorem there must be an element of order $p$. In general an element of the symmetric group of order $p$ can only be shown to be a product of disjoint $p$-cycles. However, no two  $p$-cycles are disjoint in $S_p$, so the subgroup must contain a $p$-cycle.

Comment: I am having trouble with the part after the Cauchy theorem sentence.  I am working on this problem and I do not know how to show that an element of order $p$ can only be a product of disjoint p-cycles.  I do not think we can just claim that without proof for my assignment.

Comment: @Tim you should at least be able to use that disjoint cycles commute and that every permutation is uniquely a product of disjoint cycles. When you exponentiate you're raising all cycles to the same power. Therefore if the order is $p$ every cycle has to have order $p$ (in general the order divides $p$, and $p$ is prime).